# Access VBA event code which modifying copy-paste automaticly

Tags: ms-access, vba

Situation : I have an Access form with two coordinate fields to be filled. These numerical fields are called "latitude" and "longitude." A lot of coordinates are being copy-pasted into these fields. Those coordinates contain "," for the decimal which should be ".". An error will occur if not.

Objective : Be able to update my form with copy-pasting without modifying the pasted string manually ("," --> ".").

I looked for a VBA event code for the fields latitude and longitude. I tried `=Replace([latitude];",";".")` which does not work.

Here is the first try :

```
Private Sub latitude_OnDirty()
Me!latitude = Replace(Me!latitude, ",", ".")
End Sub

Private Sub longitude_OnDirty()
Me!longitude = Replace(Me!longitude, ",", ".")
End Sub
```

VBA code is accepted but still have an error message : "The value entered isn't valid for this field." MS Access valid the type of insertion. The field is numeric and any insertion with a "," can't be a number. So, the replace command in VBA code must be before the validation. How to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Longitude and Latitude fields, go to the event properties and select the "..." on the far-right of the `AfterUpdate` event.

A window will pop-up asking what type of Builder you want to use. Choose "Code Builder."

The VBE window will pop up and place your cursor below something like `Private Sub latitude_AfterUpdate()` where `latitude` will be the name of the textbox on your form. Underneath that line, paste the following code:

`Me!Latitude = Replace(Me!Latitude, ",", ".")`

Do the same thing for Longitude, but make sure to update the `Me!Latitude` part with the actual name of the textbox.

**EDIT:**

Due to the fact that your form controls seem to be bound, I don't think you will be able to dodge the errors thrown when a comma exists in the copy/pasted data. Here is what you can do instead:

Create two new textboxes. I'll call them `LonEdit` and `LatEdit`. When you create them, drag them from the ribbon, do not use the "Use Existing Fields." This should make the "Control Source" properties empty, and should display the word "Unbound" in the textbox when the form is in design view.

Next, go to `LonEdit`'s event properties and use the code builder for the `AfterUpdate` event.

Here is the code you should insert in the `LonEdit_AfterUpdate` event:

```vb
'Test for comma
If InStr(1, Me!LonEdit, ",")>0 Then
    'Replace comma with period and copy to old textbox
    Me!Longitude = Replace(Me!LonEdit, ",", ".")
Else
    'No comma, just copy to old textbox
    Me!Longitude = Me!LonEdit
End If
'Clear the new textbox
Me!LonEdit = ""
```

Do a similar thing for the new Latitude box:

```vb
'Test for comma
If InStr(1, Me!LatEdit, ",")>0 Then
    'Replace comma with period and copy to old textbox
    Me!Latitude = Replace(Me!LatEdit, ",", ".")
Else
    'No comma, just copy to old textbox
    Me!Latitude = Me!LatEdit
End If
'Clear the new textbox
Me!LatEdit = ""
```

Once complete, try copy/pasting into the new textboxes, and then tab out of them when finished. This should replace the comma and copy to the old textbox without throwing an error. Not as nice of a solution, but it's the best I can come up with at the moment. Good Luck!

Comment: VBA code is accepted but still have an error message : "The value entered isn't valid for this field." MS Access valid the type of insertion. The field is numeric and any insert with a "," can't be a number! So, the replace in VBA code must be before the validation. How?

Comment: Error like that : https://s3.amazonaws.com/ssi-article-images/office2010/access2010/input-mask-5.jpg

Comment: Try moving the code from the `AfterUpdate` event to the `OnDirty` event.

Comment: Hm, do these fields have validation rules in the table or on the form controls? Also, are the textbox's control source property blank or not blank?

Comment: There are no fields validation rules. I did not add any form controls. So, I suppose there are none.

Comment: Latitude and longitude are never empty. So, I always update the value with a copy-paste to replace the old one.

Comment: Ok I don't think what you are trying to do is possible, but maybe another user can help. The issue is because it is a numeric field, anything with a "," will be disallowed as soon as you enter the value. There are no events that can be utilized to adjust this entry without throwing an error because BeforeUpdate will cause a runtime error if you affect the field that initially triggered an event (maybe causing an infinite loop?).

Comment: You will probably need separate textboxes to copy/paste the dirty data into, sanitize it, then paste it into old textboxes. The code above will error out if there is no comma in the input, so I will update my answer to help.